# RuntimeError: Model class rideshare.models.rideshare doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I have two separate projects kept under **two different paths**. I want to import model from one of my project `coolpool` to other project `Ajaxpython` but while doing this it is giving me the error.

```
RuntimeError: Model class rideshare.models.rideshare doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

I kept my settings.py like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'coolpool.rideshare',


]
```

If i uncomment the last line it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coolpool'`.
I have my model defined under `coolpool.rideshare.models` which i am not able to use in my files views.py in `Ajaxpython` project pasted below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/user/Desktop/millo/coolpool')
from rideshare.models import *
print(sys.path)

def validate_username(request):
    try:
        username = request.GET.get('username', None)

        data = {
            'is_taken': ridesharerequests.objects.filter().exists()
        }


    if data['is_taken']:
        data['error_message'] = 'A user with this username already exists.'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I don't have any idea what wrong i am doing here as i tried several different ways but still no luck.

I can post content from other files as well if anyone needs it here.

Comment: This is against a django app structure. You need to either get your coolpool app inside your ajaxpython project. Or make your coolpool a separate python module to be installed as a site-package in your python environment.

Comment: maybe you missed `__init__.py` in project folders.

Comment: @katoozi i have the file there still it doesn't work. I think devdob is right we can't have the project structure like this.